# Firebase snapshot prints optional

Tags: firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database, xcode7, option-type

As i run a snapshot from a firebase database below it returns

> Optional(498895446)

when i only want it to return

> 498895446

as an int. I have tried toint() but it is not working as i get an error. How can i get rid of this optional.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users + infomation").child(currentuser).child("timeStamp ")

    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock : {(snapShot) in
        let val = snapShot.value


        if snapShot.exists(){

            print("\(val)")

        }

        else if snapShot.exists() == false {
            print("snappyaintexist")
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:-

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users + infomation").child(currentuser).child("timeStamp ")

ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock : {(snapShot) in

    if let val = snapShot.value as? Int{

        print("\(val!)")

    }else{
        print("snappyaintexist")
    }
})
```